# Calculated Column for proportional map marking

Tags: spotfire, spotfire-analyst

Sorry if the title is vague, my mind is completelty blanking on what to do.

I have a data set that holds broadcast stations and counties and a Error-Ticket. I want to visualize this as a proportional size to station numbers and ticket count.

Example if I have 50 Tickets in NYC but the station count is 200 stations and 5 tickets in a county in Montana with only 1 station then Montana's error rate is statistically higher.

I figure it would be a Count([Error-Ticket]) by StationID but of course that isn't it.
I was also thinking it would be an OVER All type of function but have not gotten the desired results; in fact no results, only syntax errors.

Columns are StationID, String (KTWR, KNOE, WRTV 22.2 ); County, String (Fayette, LEE, Clark); Error-Ticket, String (ABC123, ABC124, ABC125)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the error, I think you want something proportional - so it'd be something like:

```
(COUNT([Error-Ticket]) Over [County]) / (UNIQUECOUNT([StationID]) Over [County])
```

This would tell you the number of errors happening per county in proportion to how many stations are in that county.